# Type not found in cache: System.Func for injecting a type as a Func using MVVMLight SimpleIoc

Tags: mvvm-light, simpleioc

I am registering a type in **MVVMLight SimpleIoc**,

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyInjectingClass>();
```

Then I do a constructor injection of this type as a `Func`,

```
public class MyConsumerClass
{
    readonly Func<MyInjectingClass> _injectingClassFactory;

    public MyConsumerClass(Func<MyInjectingClass> injectingClassFactory)
    {
        _injectingClassFactory = injectingClassFactory;
    }
}
```

But at *runtime*, I get this **error**,

> Type not found in cache:
>   System.Func`1[[<...>.MyInjectingClass,
>   <...>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

How can I constructor inject a type as a `Func`?

**Note:**

I'm doing this stuff in a Xamarin.IOs project.
The NuGet I use for MVVMLight SimpleIoc is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibsStd10/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that, to inject a type as a `Func`, then you have to

- Register the type first
- Then register it as a `Func` (consuming the above registered type)

That is,

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyInjectingClass>(); // should happen first

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Func<MyInjectingClass>>(
    () => () => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyInjectingClass>(
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    ));
```

The type is simply registered in a way telling it to return a `Func` object of the **MyInjectingClass**, that retrieves a *new* object each time.

`Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` makes sure a new **MyInjectingClass** object is returned for the `SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyInjectingClass>` method.